# Display output with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a [Ansible play for PGBouncer](https://github.com/balanced-ops/ansible-pgbouncer/blob/master/tasks/ops.yml#L6-L19) that displays some output from a stats module built into PGBouncer.

My issue is that when Ansible prints the output to the terminal it mangles the newlines. Instead of seeing

```
----------
| OUTPUT |
----------
```

I see

```
----------\n| OUTPUT |\n----------
```

Does anyone know how to get Ansible to "pretty print" the output?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn't a way to do what you want natively in Ansible.
You can do this as a workaround:

```
ansible-playbook ... | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: On OSX I had to use `sed -e 's/\\n/'$'\\\n/g'`. Also relevant: http://comicjk.com/20

Comment: see sorins answer https://serverfault.com/a/846232/240508 which is the correct one in 2017 and ansible >2.3

Comment: Mostly ```\n``` appear in result, so you could use this regexp in your debug message: ```msg: "{{ result.stdout | regex_replace('\\n', '\n') }}"```

Comment: unfortunately, doing this removes the nice & useful coloring you get on ansible output

Answer (score 137):

If you want more human friendly output define:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug
```

This will make ansible use the debug output module (previously named `human_log`) which **despite its unfortunate name** is less verbose and much easier to read by humans.

If you get an error that this module is not available, upgrade Ansible or add this module locally if you cannot upgrade ansible, it will work with over versions of ansible like 2.0 or probably even 1.9.

Another option to configure this is to add `stdout_callback = debug` to your ansible.cfg

Comment: this should be the *ACCEPTED* answer in  2017 the human friendly log output is shipped out of the box.

Comment: Here some more tips to make this more permanent: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27078#issuecomment-364560173

Comment: Or `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml`. I prefer it because it formats nice `fail` `msg` when I provide an object.

Answer (score 18):

Found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/iiLdiyGXlEw/WWGIHh-9emUJ) way in Ansible Project group forum:

```
- name: "Example test"
  command:
    ...
  register: test
- name: "Example test stdout"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test.stdout.split('\n') }}"
- name: "Example test stderr"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test.stderr.split('\n') }}"
```

We basically turn this into list by splitting it by newline and then printing that list.

Comment: That makes shell output much more legible! Nice!

Comment: This solution appears to have one major drawback - if the execution of the "Example test" module fails, usually the whole playbook build fails and you'll never see the formatted output, especially the one for stderr which is probably most interesting.

Comment: @René you are right. For that you can add `ignore_errors: yes` to original command and later something like `- assert: that: "test.rc == 0".

Answer (score 14):

[You can use a callback plugin](http://blog.cliffano.com/2014/04/06/human-readable-ansible-playbook-log-output-using-callback-plugin/). This will re-parse your output and is easily turned on and off.

Comment: Note: With ansible 2.0.x you need to inherit from ``CallbackBase`` imported with ``from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase`` for the callback class to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it in a format that practically mimics standard output, you can use the `debug` callback plugin with the `debug` module in Ansible 2.7+ like this:

```
- name: "Test Output"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ test_result.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're not running on parallel hosts, you can use the [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pause_module.html) module:

```
- pause:
    prompt: "{{ variable_blob.stdout }}"
```

Moves on without input by defining **minutes** or **seconds** but then user input is not captured.

Credit: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17446#issuecomment-245391682

**Note:** On parallel hosts, only output from the first host will be displayed